# Change row background color based on time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to change the row's background color on Excel based on a cell value.
For example, my C2 is set on a date format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm), and I would like to color the C row' background if the date set in C2 is in less than an hour from now.

I tried with conditional formatting, using the following formula:

`=AND($C$2 - NOW() <= TIME(01;00;00))`

but I get an error when I click on "OK".

Can anyone help me out with this, please?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[This is how the rule applies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6UBF.png)

Comment: Dates are numbers. Try `=$C$2-NOW()<1/24`

Comment: It still doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure the content of `C2` is a date and not a string that looks like a date?

Comment: It's a date I customed to fit the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
=AND((NOW()+1/24)>$C1,(NOW()-$C1)<1/24)
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed CF formula]
(in screenshot above, conditional formatting has been applied to the `$A$1:$K$10` range)

Comment: You have different regional settings from mine, so you would need to replace the `,` with `;`

Comment: I have no idea why it's not working for me... It says that there's an error in the formula :/
Could it be a compatibility problem? I'm working on Office 2016.

In fact, I'd like the row to color in green if the date and time in C2 are in more that 24 hours, orange if 24 hours or less, and red in an hour or less. It works fine for the red one but not for the others...

My formulas are like this:
```=AND($C$2-NOW() > TIME(24;0;0))```
```=AND($C$2-NOW() <= TIME(24;0;0))```
```=AND($C$2-NOW() <= TIME(1;0;0))```

Comment: Same error with a ```;```

Comment: For your conditional formatting, you need to remove the `$`2 and just use 2 IF the first row to which you've applied your conditional formatting is row 2 (I didn't hard-code the row reference in my formula, only the column reference)

Comment: Btw the `AND()` function requires TWO arguments (2 tests effectively) - your examples all only include ONE argument... (the formula in my screenshot provides 2 arguments to the `AND()` function)

Comment: Tried with ```$C2``` and ```C2``` and I still get the same error :/ "We encountered an error in this formula. Are you typing a formula?..."

Comment: Please  show the formula you have tried

Comment: I tried this:
```=AND((NOW()+1/24)>C3;(NOW()-C3)<1/24)```

Comment: That is a valid formula. Please edit your question to include a screenshot, illustrating your version of Excel, and where you are writing the formula

Comment: Well, Excel just decided to accept the exact same formula in conditionnal formatting, but  it doesn't color the row's backgound no matter what date and time I put in C4

Comment: That's because you're not using the $ sign anywhere - if you don't post a screenshot clarifying **where** you've defined your conditional formatting range, and the **exact** formula you're using then it won't be possible to advise further.

Comment: I have edited my original post with a screenshot.

Comment: That shows where the conditionally-formatted range, but not all of the formulae for each different rule...